# NDK how to get the dvm point?

Tags: java, android-ndk

now I have a question to use "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs".

but I couldn't use JNI_OnLoad method because my native code is not provid for java .

```
void *pHandle = dlopen("/system/lib/libart.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
JavaVM* m_pJvm = NULL; 
void * pFunAddr =dlsym(pHandle, "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs");
LOGD("pJNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs = %08X", pFunAddr);
pJNIGetCreatedJavaVMs = (int)pFunAddr - 1;
LOGD("call !!!!!!!");
pJNIGetCreatedJavaVMs(&m_pJvm, 0, &vm_count);
LOGD("pJNIGetCreatedJavaVMs result is %d", result);
```

when I call the JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs, process was crashed.

I didn't found what happend in IDA.

who can help me !!!!!!!!!!!!!! THX

ps:JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs  method is found in the android source code.

and  another method  is  use  runtime(libart.so) or gdvm(libdvm.so).

Comment: my code have  bug    pJNIGetCreatedJavaVMs = (int)pFunAddr - 1;  change  pJNIGetCreatedJavaVMs = (int)pFunAddr;  the  "-1"  beacause I found the API  address in IDA  is less my code found address.   I think it's   thumb and  arm   change mode  caused.  so I add the "-1".   now   it's not need.   and   I have get the right dvm.

Answer (score 1):

Some code from my native app, it is build in the AOSP source tree.

I am not sure if it could work in NDK

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android_runtime/AndroidRuntime.h>
...
JNIEnv *env;
jint res;
JavaVM *jvm = AndroidRuntime::getJavaVM();
assert(jvm != NULL);
res = jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
assert(res >= 0);
```

Comment: yes.  I can found the runtime  when  IDA  attach the process.  but  in my ndk path   I didn't found the android_runtime path and the AndroidRuntime.h header file.   thx for your share.

Comment: extern "C" jint JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(JavaVM** vms, jsize, jsize* vm_count) {
  Runtime* runtime = Runtime::Current();
  if (runtime == NULL) {
    *vm_count = 0;
  } else {
    *vm_count = 1;
    vms[0] = runtime->GetJavaVM();
  }
  return JNI_OK;
}
this is the JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs code.  it's call the runtime.  but the runtime.so don't have export for getJavaVM .